# Netty AsyncRestTemplate Https URL - Connection reset by peer

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, netty

I'm using `Netty4ClientHttpRequestFactory to configure asyncresttemplate,

```
public AsyncRestTemplate asyncRestTemplate(Netty4ClientHttpRequestFactory netty4ClientHttpRequestFactory,
                                               @Qualifier("AsyncClientLoggingInterceptor") AsyncClientHttpRequestInterceptor clientHttpRequestInterceptor) {
        AsyncRestTemplate restTemplate = new AsyncRestTemplate(netty4ClientHttpRequestFactory);
        List<AsyncClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = new ArrayList<>();
        interceptors.add(clientHttpRequestInterceptor);
        restTemplate.setInterceptors(Collections.unmodifiableList(interceptors));
        return restTemplate;
    }

    @Bean(name = "netty4ClientHttpRequestFactory")
    public Netty4ClientHttpRequestFactory netty4ClientHttpRequestFactory() {
        Netty4ClientHttpRequestFactory netty4ClientHttpRequestFactory = new Netty4ClientHttpRequestFactory();
        netty4ClientHttpRequestFactory.setConnectTimeout(CONNECT_TIMEOUT);
        netty4ClientHttpRequestFactory.setReadTimeout(CONNECT_TIMEOUT);
        return netty4ClientHttpRequestFactory;
    }


ListenableFuture<ResponseEntity<Void>> future =
                asyncRestTemplate.exchange(message.getToUrl(), HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, Void.class);
```

Everything works fine with HTTP POST but with Https it throws the following exception,

```
   java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380) ~[?:1.8.0_74]
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:288) ~[netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1100) ~[netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:372) ~[netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:123) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:624) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:559) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:476) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:438) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_74]
```

Answer (score 1):

On of the reasons for the error message "Connection reset by peer" is, as the client is waiting for a response from the remote service and the connection was closed prematurely.

I configured the Netty4ClientHttpRequestFactory with,

```
netty4ClientHttpRequestFactory.setSslContext(SslContextBuilder.forClient().build());
```